# How to create a loop and always move to the next used cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying data from one worksheet into another, transposing and auto-filling using a macro but i want to create a loop and have it always select the next cell ("A8" & "B8")in the previous worksheet (MF2) to be copied instead of having to manually change the cell. This is the macro i'm using

```
Sub Test1()

    Sheets("MF2").Select
    Range("A8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("MF2").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Columns("B").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "B")).Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True

    Dim endRow As Long
    endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":A" & endRow)
    Range("C1").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":C" & endRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give us a graphical representation of your data.  It looks like you are getting data of different shapes and copying it.  Do you have the data in rows with a row heading and transposing it to Columns with column headings?

Comment: The data has no heading. The data being copied ("A8") is one single cell and ("B8") is multiple rows which is transpose to a column.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First, don't activate and select everything. Use variables to store references to your source and destination. Second, `Range.Copy` takes an optional destination parameter. You can copy and paste in one fell swoop. Here's the code.

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = Sheets("MF2")

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A8")

    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Set destSheet = Sheets("Sheet3")

    Dim destRange As Range
    With destSheet
        Set destRange = .Columns(1).Find("", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
    End With

    sourceRange.Copy destRange

End Sub
```

And yes, I realize this answers exactly none of your questions.

Comment: probably best to just leave a comment pointing to the (relatively) canonical: [How to avoid using Select/Activate in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Yeah @DavidZemens, maybe, but this way I know he actually saw how it's done.

Comment: Well, it does answer the question `How to create a loop and always move to the next used cell in VBA` in some ways, I don't see any reason why this is downvoted.

Comment: I understand to issue with using Select/Activate so i'll recreate the macro using your suggestions. Thanks